# Merge videos objective C right orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this class https://github.com/mkoehnke/MKOVideoMerge to merge multiples videos, it's working fine, but the final video it's generated with the wrong orientation.

Comment: I am also using this. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to make it work like this :) hope it helps! https://gist.github.com/javiersuazo/bb36083bdaa0a51d52323d997a84712e